# How can I parse a file name string in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab

I would like to have the original string `'black.txt'` to be parsed into `a = 'black'` and `ext = '.txt'`. Every filename/string is going to have the extension `'.txt'`. I'm wondering what would be the easiest way of achieving this in MATLAB so that I can concatenate the new string appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the standard [strrep](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html) function from Matlab works well enough in my case.

Comment: Did you mean to say STRTOK (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strtok.html) instead of STRREP?

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using the [FILEPARTS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html) function to parse a file name string. Here's an example:

```
>> fileString = '\home\matlab\black.txt';
>> [filePath,fileName,fileExtension] = fileparts(fileString)

filePath =
   \home\matlab

fileName =
   black

fileExtension =
   .txt
```

You can then put the file string back together with simple string concatenation (for just the file name) or using the [FULLFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html) function (for an absolute or partial file path):

```
fileString = [fileName fileExtension];  %# Just the file name
fileString = fullfile(filePath,[fileName fileExtension]);  %# A file path
```

Using FULLFILE is easier and more robust with respect to running your code on different operating systems, since it will choose the appropriate file separator for you ("\" for Windows or "/" for UNIX).

Answer (score 2):

fileparts is probably better for this application.

E.g. [PATHSTR,NAME,EXT,VERSN] = fileparts('matlab_script.m');

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3028) at the Matlab Central Repository.

Probably this is what you want.

```
%EXPLODE Splits string into pieces. 
% EXPLODE(STRING,DELIMITERS) returns a cell array with the pieces 
% of STRING found between any of the characters in DELIMITERS. 
%
```